# How to use function SQLGetPrivateProfileString from odbccp32.dll, using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, ms-access, odbc, dsn

I found this discussion thread dating back to 2004:

[Calling SQLDataSources](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/ad/345347.html)

It shows how to retrieve a list of DSN entries without poking into the Registry directly.

So far, no problem with Delphi.  BTW, I'm using Delphi 2007 on Windows 7.

Now, I'd like to select only the entries which refer to an MS Access database, so I tried to add only a few lines to the example.

First I declared this:

```
function SQLGetPrivateProfileString( 
  lpszSection, lpszEntry, lpszDefault, lpszRetBuffer: PChar; 
  cbRetBuffer: Integer; 
  lpszFilename: PChar): integer; stdcall;
```

And under implementation:

```
function SQLGetPrivateProfileString; external 'odbccp32.dll' name 'SQLGetPrivateProfileString';
```

Then I added the following line somewhere in the middle of the example:

```
Result := SQLGetPrivateProfileString('ODBC Data Sources', Buffer1, 'Driver', RetBuf, 100, 'odbc.ini');
```

with `RetBuf` declared as `PChar`.

I was able to retrieve the Driver strings as shown in the Registry under ODBC. Calling `GetMem` and `FreeMem` to initialize and cleanup `RetBuf` appeared essential to keep my program stable.

My question is: how can I retrieve the path to the `*.MDB` file involved (or `*.ACCDB` file). I tried this to no avail:

```
SQLGetPrivateProfileString(nil, Buffer1, 'DBQ', RetBuf, 128, 'odbc.ini')
```

Of course, I'd be interested in a good alternative for the `SQLGetPrivateProfileString()` function.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I cross-posted a similar question in the "comp.lang.pascal.delphi.databases" newsgroup, sorry.

Comment: Do what is the question exactly. You have a bug in your code but you didn't show any code or even appear to do any debugging.

Comment: specify Delphi version. I wonder if you are mislead by Unicode vs ansi strings and chars...

Comment: The declaration shown is OK for Delphi 2007 and earlier, where `PChar` is `PAnsiChar`, but is not OK for Delphi 2009+, where `PChar` is `PWideChar`.  `SQLGetPrivateProfileString()` does not accept Unicode strings, only Ansi strings, so you should use `PAnsiChar` explicitly instead of `PChar` generically.

Comment: I guess you need the path to the file before connecting to the database? Because once you are connected, you can call `SQLGetInfo()` with the property `SQL_DATA_SOURCE_NAME` and that will hold the path to the mdb-file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all the suggestions. Yes, I plan to use this for a program that lets the user choose the database file (*.MDB or *.ACCDB), i.e. before connecting to any database. Concerning the function SQLGetPrivateProfileString: I was especially confused due to its argument lpszDefault. I've realised that it is enough to give an empty string for this argument. At request, I'm adding my code below (with few details removed). For Delphi versions higher than 2007, a few things will have to be adapted.

```
const 
  SQL_SUCCESS = 0;
  SQL_NO_DATA = 100;
  SQL_FETCH_NEXT = 1;
  SQL_FETCH_FIRST = 2
  SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH = 32;
  SQL_MAX_OPTION_STRING_LENGTH = 256;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  EnvironmentHandle: Pointer;;
  Buffer1: array[0..SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH] of Char;
  Buffer2: array[0..SQL_MAX_OPTION_STRING_LENGTH] of Char;
  RetBuf1, RetBuf2: PChar;
  Len1, Len2: SmallInt;
  DataSourceName, DriverName, PathToFile: string;
  Result, i: Integer;
begin
  if SQLAllocEnv(EnvironmentHandle) = SQL_SUCCESS then
  try
    try
      i := 0;
      Result := SQLDataSources(EnvironmentHandle, SQL_FETCH_FIRST, Buffer1, SizeOf(Buffer1), Len1, Buffer2, SizeOf(Buffer2), Len2);
      if Result = SQL_SUCCESS then
      repeat
        try
          // Initialise
          DataSourceName := '';
          DriverName := '';
          PathToFile := '';

          // Prepare to find out about the driver
          SetString(DataSourceName, Buffer1, Len1);
          GetMem(RetBuf1, 200);
          Result := SQLGetPrivateProfileString('ODBC Data Sources', Buffer1, '', RetBuf1, 200, 'odbc.ini');

          // If it went well, then only show the result when it's an Access database
          if Result > 0 then
          begin
            if (Pos('access', LowerCase(RetBuf1)) > 0) then
            begin
              // Get the driver of the current DSN entry
              SetString(DriverName, RetBuf1, Result);

              // Try to retrieve the path to the file
              if (Pos('access', LowerCase(RetBuf1)) > 0) then
              begin
                // The Access database files are registered with key 'DBQ'              
                GetMem(RetBuf2, 200);
                Result := SQLGetPrivateProfileString(Buffer1, 'DBQ', '', RetBuf2, 200, 'odbc.ini')
                if Result > 0 then
                begin
                  SetString(PathToFile, RetBuf2, Result);
                  if Pos('~', PathToFile) > 0 then PathToFile := WinapiGetLongPathName(PathToFile);
                end;
                FreeMem(RetBuf2);

                // Arrange the output, if it's relevant
                if not FileExists(PathToFile) then Continue;
                AdvStringGrid1.Cells[0, i + 1] := DataSourceName;
                AdvStringGrid1.Cells[1, i + 1] := DriverName;
                AdvStringGrid1.Cells[2, i + 1] := PathToFile;
                AdvStringGrid1.RowCount := i + 2;
                Inc(i);
              end;
            end;
          end;

          // Prepare for the next loop
          FreeMem(RetBuf1);
        finally
          Result := SQLDataSources(EnvironmentHandle, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, Buffer1, SizeOf(Buffer1), Len1, Buffer2, SizeOf(Buffer2), Len2);
        end;
      until (Result = SQL_NO_DATA)

     except on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    SQLFreeEnv(EnvironmentHandle);
  end;
end;
```